nestjs input type for schema first approach
In the following example I'm trying to add a validation of @Min(5) to my count field in my input, but it has no effect, I'll send 2 to it and it won't complain why I sent anything lower than 5.
My schema :
input AuthorIncrementViewsInput {
    count: Int!
}

type Mutation {
  authorIncrementViews(authorIncrementViewsInput: AuthorIncrementViewsInput!): Int!
}

The resolver:
import { Args, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthorIncrementViewsInput } from './authors.inputs';
import { AuthorsService } from './authors.service';

@Resolver('Author')
export class AuthorsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly authorsService: AuthorsService) {}

  @Mutation()
  async authorIncrementViews(
    @Args('authorIncrementViewsInput')
    authorIncrementViewsInput: AuthorIncrementViewsInput,
  ) {
    return this.authorsService.authorIncrementViews(authorIncrementViewsInput);
  }
}

The input:
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Min } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class AuthorIncrementViewsInput {
  @Field()
  @Min(5)
  count: number;
}

Let's test it:

mutation {
  authorIncrementViews(authorIncrementViewsInput: {count: 52})
}

The result is :
{
  "data": {
    "authorIncrementViews": 102
  }
}

Which is correct but I need to get the validation error (for @Min) instead of the actual result.
